Can I limit the final charge voltage of NiCd cells?
I want to use 4 series NiCd to directly power a device.
The problem is that NiCd at full charge may exceed the recommended voltage limit of 5.25V (or 1.325V per cell.)
Based on charge curves, it seems that NiCd cell voltage has a sharp rise near full charge.
Does NiCd cell voltage directly correlate to amount of charge in the cells, when discharging or charging?
Could I simply use a voltage detector to disconnect charger as soon as the desired voltage level is reached?
I will only use slow charge (<0.1C) and would be charging them in series.

NiMH has superseded NiCd technology a couple of decades ago, and lithiums have been common for a long time too. Any reason to keep using NiCd technology? For instance, an USB power bank would output regulated 5V to your device.

I have a bunch of these NiCd cells I bought a couple years ago.

FWIW, I've float-charged a set of 4 NiMH at 1.4 V per cell for the last 5 years, and they've not let out the magic oooze yet. YMMV.

The easiest way to charge a NiCd is at C/10 for 16 hours. NiCd cells can be charged at C/10 regardless of their state of charge. The best practice is to limit the charge voltage to 1.41 VPC and set a timer to terminate the charge after 16 hours.
NiCd fast chargers use one of two or both charge termination methods, voltage signature or temperature. Most manufacturers use temperature to terminate the charge at 50 degrees centigrade.
You can follow up by going to Battery University and reading about charging NiCd battery chemistry. Modern smart chargers use a Delta temperature rise or a voltage dip. A NiCd voltage will dip when fully charged, with a quick temperature rise.
Alternatively, use a C/20 trickle charge rate and forget about it.

What if the charge voltage is limited to 1.325v instead?

Jay, now that I know you have a bag of older cells, the absolute best and safest way to charge/restore them is to use a slow charge of C/10 for 16 hours. If the cells are usable, they will be fully restored and charged up. For 4S, you will need a 5.6 to 5.7-volt source with a C/10 or .1C current limiter. 5.25-volts is not enough.

For most NiCd cell discharge curves that I see on google the voltage is nominally 1.2-1.3V, while the charging curves start at 1.4V and go up from there.
Does cell voltage drop after charging when the charger is disconnected perhaps?
Or just some inaccurate graphs?

@Jay Yes, sir, the surface charge will bleed off. Nickel chemistry batteries are more difficult to charge because they do not use traditional set voltages to charge them. They are charged with a constant current supply until either a time limit is reached or charging slowly like you intend to do. Faster charging, like C/3, requires either a temperature or voltage dip to determine when the full charge is reached. The nominal voltage is 1.2 volts, and discharge is 1 volt. Seriously, read the link I gave you.
Using a C/10 Charge rate makes life easy so you can apply KISS (keep it simple stupid

I did some tests on the batteries since to have some 1st hand data. I left on roughly c/10 for the amount of time required to get full charge

*from empty, assuming 50% efficiency.
The final cell voltage was 1.42-1.45V straight off charge and quickly dropped below 1.4V powering the load.

@jay, that is what you should see. Just a little load will bleed the cells down to nominal 1.2 .
